# ThreadPoolExecutor as an Queue?

Tags: java, threadpool

I used `ThreadPoolExecuter` as a queue for my transaction processing applications. Following is the code snipped and values used in prod servers:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    corePool, maxPool,keepAlive,TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

1. Core Pool and Maxpool configured as "50" in the performance Load servers.
2. Transaction processing time on each transaction will be 300 MS.
3. When we sent 30 tps to that server,  CPU usage is reached as 100 percentage and server is not responding.

Is there any alternative solution to handle 70 to 80 TPS using that server? Can someone guide me the best approach to handle this?

Comment: 300 milliseconds (i.e. 0.3 seconds) is a LONG time.  Each core could do a little over 3 transactions in a second. Number of cores will determine your throughput; e.g. 4 cores would support 12 tps; 8 cores would support 24 tps.  For 80 tps you would need 27 cores.  INSTEAD, you likely want to look at reducing you processing time.  What are you doing that it takes 300ms?!?

Comment: You are using the *queue* as a queue. You are using the Executor as an executor.

Comment: You need to run a profiler to see what's actually taking all the time then the optimise the slow bits. At the moment you are looking to optimise something that might have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Lot of DB validation is there as part of transactions processing.Will find out the queries and fine-tuning.

Answer (score 0):

That the server is at 100% CPU with 30 tps indicates  that you don't have a problem with work scheduling ( do some profiling to see how the time is spent). To achieve 80 tps you may need to optimize individual transaction processing and/or add CPU s.